# ¿Como pasar un operador ternary a condicional if en php?

Tags: php, php5

Hace poco en contre con una operación Ternary que esta copiado aquí abajo,

```
variable1 += (variable1.length < 1 ? "  " : '|') +(array_varible1[elemento_for].length >0 ? array_varible1[elemento_for] : " ");
```

Funciona perfecta mente y hace todo lo que estoy pidiendo, pero conforme estaba le yendo medí cuenta que es un simplificado de un condicional if, me gustaría saber si alguien puede traducir este operador Ternary a una condición if.

Gracias Chicos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seria algo asi:

```
$variable1 =""


if(variable1.length < 1){
 $variable1 += " ";

}else{
 $variable1 +='|';
}

if(array_varible1[elemento_for].length >0)
{
    $variable1 +=array_varible1[elemento_for];

} else{
    $variable1 +=" "
}
```

los simbolos ? es un condicional y lo siguiente al simbolo se ejecutara si es verda, mientras que los que este despues de los : se ejecutaria si la condicion es falsa ejemplo:

```
 echo 1==1 ? "si" : "no";
```